# Magento getting products in a category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i think this is very simple but i have been trying for a while and nothing.
I have a category and I want to show all the products in a phtml but with some customizations.

But i cant get the products in a category. I have the category with this code:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Gifts');
```

I have tried this but didnt work:

```
$categoryId = 25;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->load();
```

I got it working using this awful code, but of course there is a better way:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Gifts');
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // select all attributes
foreach ($collection as $product) {
  foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $category_id) {
      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
      if ($category->getName()=='Gifts'){
          echo $product->getName()."<br/>";
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$products = $_category->getProductCollection();

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //for full product model
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
}
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. And I know its the right category because when I get the size its ok. I also tried to echo something inside the foreach loop, but it's never reached.